# SQL Server error on opening connection in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

EDIT:
For those coming here with similar error, my fault was using 'true' instead of SSPI for integrated security.

Here is the original post.

I'm using Excel 2016 (office 365 professional pro). In VBA I have added reference to 'Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library' and in the code below I am getting an error on the opens statement when trying to connect to SQL Server 2012 or 2008:

> Run-time error '-2147217887 (80040e21)':
>   Automation error

Checking the errors object shows

- multiple-step oledb operation generated errors. Check each ole db status value
- number: -2147217887
- Source: Provider

I know the connection string and user is fine and it is the same I use in c# code and via ODBC it is fine. I've also tried using user credentials, 2.8 oledb library, and even changing to 'database' and 'server' in the DSN. The only difference is in C# I use `System.Data.SqlClient` as the provider.

Any idea how to get more information or any idea what could be wrong.

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sql As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim val As String

'MsgBox "Start"
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE;data source=MYSERVER;Integrated Security=true"
conn.Open
```

EDIT:
I can create a connection via data connections and in my ODC file it says this:

```
  <odc:Connection odc:Type="OLEDB">
   <odc:ConnectionString>Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Data Source=SERVER;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=xxx;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;Initial Catalog=MYDATABASE</odc:ConnectionString>
   <odc:CommandType>Table</odc:CommandType>
  </odc:Connection>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to narrow the issue by trying to link your excel though the **"data>other sources"** in the excel menu.
This will not fix the code, but should help you see if anything is wrong with your connection string.

Comment: That is fine and connects straight away. See my original post, I have added something.

Comment: THANK! Indirectly anyway! I opened the ODC file it created and it used 'Integrated Security=SSPI. I changed it from true to this and it worked. This is strange as I presumed SSPI/true were aliases.

How would someone figure out the actual error without trial and error, i.e. is there any object data that can be read?

Comment: You're welcome, that was the idea behind the manipulation :-)